# Modifying and Using Variables Across Files in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I have two View Controllers. In the first one, let's call it ViewControllerA, I have a Button. In the second view controller, let's call it ViewControllerB, I have a View. The Button in ViewControllerA performs a segue to ViewControllerB. Normally, the View in ViewControllerB has its isHidden property set to true.

How do I make it so when I click the Button in ViewControllerA, the View in ViewControllerB has its isHidden property changed to false?

This is what I have for ViewControllerA

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

var buttonPressed : Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func theButton(_ sender: Any) {
    buttonPressed = true

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToControllerB", sender: self)
}

}
```

And this is what I have for ViewControllerB:

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

var isButtonPressed : Bool = ViewControllerA().buttonPressed


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if isButtonPressed == true {

        myView.isHidden = false
    }
    else {

        myView.isHidden = true
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `prepareForSegue` method in `ViewControllerA` like so:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "goToControllerB" {
       if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB {
           destinationVC.isButtonPressed = false
       }
   }
}
```

And in `ViewControllerB`, change the variable:

```
var isButtonPressed: Bool?
```

Comment: I'm getting the "'override' can only be specified on class member" error when I do this. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you put the method inside of the view controller curly braces({})?

Comment: @Xcoder you should say prepareForSegue  with  performSegue  not instead of it

Comment: If the OP has a segue in the storyboard, then he/she can just remove the `performSegue` call.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Edited my answer.

Comment: I got it. So I needed to add that prepareForSegue method after the IBAction and then keep the performSegue method inside the IBAction. Thanks so much! This was really killing me 

Comment: Yeah, sorry for any confusion caused. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just override prepare(for:sender:) in your ViewControllerA like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "goToControllerB", let destination = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB else { return }

    destination.isButtonPressed = true
}
```

Then, inside viewDidLoad() function in your ViewControllerB, set visibility of the view:

```
myView.isHidden = !isButtonPressed
```